# How to make selection on drop down list (DynamicForm) using JavaScript in SmartClient?

Tags: javascript, smartclient

Here is a drop down list in SmartClient: http://www.smartclient.com/#dropdownGrid.

I want to make a selection using JavaScript. Like, I run some JavaScript in console, and the drop list will select a specific item.

I did some research, found a code snap to do this (*the code is in Java, but I think there should be similar functions in JavaScript*):

```
Record rec = perdomainGrid.getRecordList().find("domaine_id", domaine_id);
perdomainGrid.selectSingleRecord(rec);
```

If I want to make selection, first I need to obtain `perdomainGrid` object. In my above giving link, the drop down list id in GWT is `exampleForm` (*can be seen in dropDownGrid.js tab*). I try to get the object by:

```
var form = isc.DynamicForm.getById("exampleForm");
```

`form` does exist, but there is no `getRecordList()` function on it, there is `selectSingleRecord()` function on it though.

I try to check `form`'s class by `form.className`, its value is `normal`. I don't know what does that mean.

I'm kind of confused now. Could somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isc_SelectItem_5` has a function called `pickValue()`, it takes one parameter `SKU`. This function can be used to select item.

```
var itemName = "Letter Tray Front Load Tenex 200 Class Blk #23001";
var data = isc_SelectItem_5.optionDataSource.cacheData;
var targetSKU = data.find(function(e) {
    if (e.itemName == itemName) {
        return e;
    }
}).SKU;
isc_SelectItem_5.pickValue(targetSKU);
```